# Importing CSV to BigQuery parsing error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a CSV with 225 rows and see BigQuery expects the schema to be

column1_name:data_type,

I have removed all spaces however BigQuery doesn't like my schema it returns "Parsing Error" and returns the first field name.

my pasted schema looks like this (partial)

transaction_status:STRING(6),dollarsobligated:NUMERIC(10,2),baseandexercisedoptionsvalue:NUMERIC(10,2),baseandalloptionsvalue:NUMERIC(12,2),maj_agency_cat:STRING(35),mod_agency:STRING(37),maj_fund_agency_cat:STRING(35),contractingofficeagencyid:STRING(37),contractingofficeid:STRING(51),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the dimensioning, not needed. Declaring "String" is optional, as it's the default. Instead of numeric, do "float".

So

> transaction_status:STRING(6),dollarsobligated:NUMERIC(10,2),baseandexercisedoptionsvalue:NUMERIC(10,2),baseandalloptionsvalue:NUMERIC(12,2),maj_agency_cat:STRING(35),mod_agency:STRING(37),maj_fund_agency_cat:STRING(35),contractingofficeagencyid:STRING(37),contractingofficeid:STRING(51),

should be

> transaction_status,dollarsobligated:float,baseandexercisedoptionsvalue:float,baseandalloptionsvalue:float,maj_agency_cat,mod_agency,maj_fund_agency_cat,contractingofficeagencyid,contractingofficeid